# Are there any new parallel programing features in Delphi 2006 - XE?

Tags: delphi, parallel-processing

Are there any new parallel programing features in Delphi 2006 - XE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a [TThread.CreateAnonymousThread](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TThread.CreateAnonymousThread) in Delphi XE which allows for simple execution of background tasks.

A trivial demo:

```
TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
  procedure begin
    Sleep(10000); // replace with a real workload
  end
).Start;
```

Answer (score 7):

Minimal in the releases themselves.  In Delphi 2009 they added support for anonymous methods in `TThread.Synchronize`, and in XE they added a thread-communication queue to `Generics.Collections`.

But the community has contributed some interesting stuff.  For example, check out [OmniThreadLibrary](http://code.google.com/p/omnithreadlibrary/).

Answer (score 4):

IMO the most powerful and the least known multithreading feature introduced after Delphi 7 is [TThread.Queue](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TThread.Queue) method. For example, instead of

```
Synchronize(
  procedure
  begin
    Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add(‘Begin Execution’);
  end);
```

you can use

```
Queue(
  procedure
  begin
    Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add(‘Begin Execution’);
  end);
```

[TThread.Queue](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TThread.Queue) is an alternative to [TThread.Synchronize](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TThread.Synchronize) that allows a worker thread to continue without waiting (with Synchronize call a worker thread waits until the main thread finished execution of the synchronized code) - a really nice feature that can be used as a replacement for custom message processing with **PostMessage**.

Comment: FYI, Delphi 10.2 Tokyo has added [`TThread.ForceQueue()`.](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.ForceQueue), which is similar to `TThread.Queue()` except that it always queues the specified code for later execution *even when called in the main UI thread*. `TThread.Queue()` does not queue execution when called in the main UI thread, it executes immediately, like `TThread.Synchronize()` does.

Answer (score 1):

Since 2010 or XE threads can be named, though this is only visible in the debugger (not in e.g. sysinternals stuff like procesxp)

Answer (score 0):

Currently no multicores cpu even if there are codes to run in multithreads. lock and unlock issue here is why

1. memory manager. it is better than in the past
2. string is reference count
3. interface is reference count

Cheer

Comment: "Currently no multicores cpu"  -- are you saying that if I create threads, they *all* run on one core?

Comment: They can run on all cores but when ever there is a lock code called/used, it can assert on mem bus which cause other cpus/cores to be stopped for duration of call. Let say you have a four cores cpu and four threads running on each core. when the lock occurred, all other cpus/cores must be halted. Here is for your reading: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/implementing-scalable-atomic-locks-for-multi-core-intel-em64t-and-ia32-architectures/

Comment: That's exactly what we wanted to avoid in our Enhanced RTL, and with our SynScaleMM. See http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?id=57  But the main bottleneck is definitively the memory manager, not those LOCK asm instructions. That's when SynScaleMM becomes handy.